# CSS transform rotate animation does not work on anchor elements in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transforms

I don't why but the transform I am applying to the < a> tag does not work in firefox. works fine in chrome, opera, ie and safari. I am using it in my wordpress site like this

```
<a id="spinner" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name');?></a>
```

here's an example of a < div> and a < a> which works fine in other browsers than firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/6HCRs/344/

here's my code

```
  /* all other browsers */
  @keyframes spinner {
    from {
      -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
      transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to {
      -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
      transform: rotateY(-360deg);
    }
  }

    #spinner {
    -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;

    animation-name: spinner;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 5s;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

  #spinner:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1 - Terminology - Transformable Element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element)
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-level) or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose [display property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform.

There are some cross-browser inconsistencies, but in order for the `transform` property to have an effect on the element, the `display` property shouldn't be `inline`.

Anchor elements are `inline` by default, therefore you need to change the `display` to `inline-block` or `block` in order for it to work in Firefox. Changing the `display` property's value to `inline-block` renders the elements as [atomic inline-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), and therefore the elements become ["transformable"](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) by definition.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ng563ux1/)

```
#spinner {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yep, there are still a lot of browser inconsistencies when it comes to Transform + Animation/Transition. Here is one case where the transform actually happens on inline element and then snaps back in Chrome - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768220/why-does-my-transform-snap-back/31768872#31768872.

Comment: @Harry Excellent--that looks like a very in-depth answer! I'll have to read through that :)

Comment: Thanks :) I'd definitely recommend reading the referenced articles. They have quite a lot of information on how the actual page rendering process works.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #spinner:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;

  }
```