# Keyframes animation not working on element of :hover in moz and

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, keyframe

I ran into a problem where I want to animate some text inside a button on :hover. To target the text of the button I wrapped it inside a span element and target it like this:

```
button:hover span{
  animation:...
}
```

This works nicely in chrome, but fails in firefox and safari. It seems that the browsers don't support animating children of :hover which seems very weird. Does anyone know the cause of this?

I'm attaching a link with the particular use case on codepen.
http://codepen.io/JonasB/pen/cded300cb982d592b9db4cb0da2191d8

Comment: This issue is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768220/why-does-my-transform-snap-back/31768872#31768872. Not quite a dupe because that is for transition and this one is animation but I am linking it here because you may find the explanation provided in that answer helpful. Animations and Transitions generally work in a way similar to each other.

Answer (score 4):

It's due to the fact that the span is an inline element, adding property of display: inline-block fixes the issue.

This thread explains in more detail: [Why can't inline elements be transformed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33305109/why-cant-inline-elements-be-transformed)

Comment: Thank you, I was so distracted by the fact that it worked in chrome and never thought about it.